# Android - add a view to ViewAnimator at the beginning

Tags: android, viewanimator

I need to add a view in the beginning of the views at ViewAnimator. How can I do that? ViewAnimator.addView(view) adds view to the end of the list. But I need it to be added at the beginning. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ViewAnimator has an additional method for adding view. You can add the view at index 0.

```
addView(View child, int index, ViewGroup.LayoutParams params)
Adds a child view with the specified layout parameters.
```

Comment: Can I use negative indexes there? Does it increment existing indexes? So, if I have element with index 0 - "A" and element with index 1 - "B" and addView(C, 0) - will "B" now accessable as index 2 ?

Comment: Don't use negative indexes, the ViewGroup class will automatically rearrange the indexes...

See source: http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.1_r2/android/view/ViewGroup.java#ViewGroup.addInArray%28android.view.View%2Cint%29